# Memory management issue: Object used after release

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, memory-management

This code is returning an error: 
 
458:3 Reference-counted object is used after it is released

```
 - (id)createObjectFromURL: (NSURL*)URL
                    query: (NSDictionary*)query {
  id target = nil;

    if (self.instantiatesClass) 
  {
    target = [_targetClass alloc];
  } 

  else 
  {
    target = [_targetObject retain];
  }

  id returnValue = nil;
  if (_selector) 
  {
    returnValue = [self invoke:target withURL:URL query:query];
  } 
  else if (self.instantiatesClass) 
  {
    returnValue = [target init];
  }

  [target autorelease];
  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you try to do this:

```
else if (self.instantiatesClass) 
{
  returnValue = [[target init] autorelease];
}
return returnValue;
```

Because you're not init ing the target if you don't go to else if.

Comment: Also, try to use the static analyzer more often.

Comment: MiRAGe; Which is this "static analyzer"?

Comment: It's like a compiler that can automatically find trivial bugs or typos for you. The shortcut is Apple-shift-A or Build->Build and analyze. So did my solution work?

Comment: I used this "Build and analyze" to generate that error :). It worked. Thanks